# how to pass 2 objects from form1 to form2

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

how to pass 2 object from form1 to form2 in winforms using C#

i know to pass one object like this:

```
Form G = new frm2(sc);
G.ShowDialog();
```

thank in advance

Comment: what is the problem here Form g=new frm2(obj1,obj2); g.ShowDialog(); add parameter in frm2(,) Constructor to overload.

Answer (score 3):

Make constructor with 2 arguments like below :

```
public partial class frm2 :Form
    {
         public frm2(List<int> object1, List<string> object2)
        {
        }

         .....
         ......
    }
```

And call like :

```
Form G = new frm2(object1, object2); 
G.ShowDialog();
```

**Second Option :**

You can make properties in forms and pass it like below :

```
Form G = new frm2(); 
G.Object1 = object1;
G.Object2 = object2;
G.ShowDialog();
```

Your frm2 will be like this :

```
public partial class frm2 : Form
{
     public frm2()
    {
    }

     public List<int> Object1 { get; set; }
     public List<string> Object2 { get; set; }
     .....
     ......
}
```

Comment: Give you feedback if my answer helps you

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make a constructor taking two arguments?

```
Form G = new frm2(obj1, obj2);
G.ShowDialog();
```

With frm2:

```
public partial class frm2 : Form {

    private Object1 _obj1;
    private Object2 _obj2;

    void frm2(Object1 obj1, Object2 obj2) {
        this._obj1 = obj1;
        this._obj2 = obj2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just modify the constructor of frm2 to accept 2 parameters:

```
public void frm2(object obj1, object obj2)
{
    //to do...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second method is to write an own constructor which accepts those two objects. If it's mandatory for the form, then hide the default constructor and with that force the passing of the two objects.